# SVN "repair move" from the command-line

Tags: svn

My IDE doesn't know that I use Subversion, and any time I rename a class (Java) it renames the file without notifying the version control system. I would of course like the file's history to be retained. I understand that in TortoiseSVN there is an option called "repair move" that fixes the move, but that's not an option since I'm on Ubuntu. Is there a way to repair the move from the command-line?

Comment: I looked in the TortoiseSVN source code, it moves the file back manually and then "svn move"s it back to its destination. Of course, I can do that with the command line, I'm just asking if there's an easier way.

Comment: You might want to mention what your IDE is - there are lots of IDE-specific tools.

Comment: @shaunmartin, does it really matter what IDE he is using here?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the Java space but in .NET-land VisualStudio has AnkhSVN which allows you to do the rename all within the IDE - it performs the rename in the project, file and SVN.  I'm guessing there are similar tools for Eclipse or whatever you're using.  You could skip using the command line altogether.

Comment: @Lasse, Sure, if there is an svn plugin for that ide, it would be easier to just use that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you remember the old name/location of the file:

```
mv new-filename old-filename
svn mv old-filename new-filename
```

You, of course, need the Subversion command-line client installed, which you probably have.  If not, `sudo aptitude install subversion subversion-client` should do the trick.

Per your comment, no, I don't know that there is an easier way than this.  If you're not sure what your old filename was, `svn stat` may give you a hint.

Comment: I was just researching this question for a colleague and found [this](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/documentation.html?page=commands.detect-moves) which is rather cool if you have a whole load of moved files.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your .bashrc

```
svn-repair() { mv -n -- "$2" "$1" && svn mv -- "$1" "$2"; }
```

then you can type

```
svn-repair old-filename new-filename
```

Comment: shouldn't the usage be `svn-repair old-filename new-filename` ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to repair the move from the command-line?

No, this is [SVN issue 1802](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1082). It has been open since 2003 so don't hold your breath.