# Fixing subversion repository with manually moved files

Tags: svn

I have refactored a Java Ant project in order to use Maven. The task has consisted mostly in moving files from one path to another, while adding a pom.xml here and there, but the problem comes when I want to commit changes. Since I've manually moved files (not using `svn mv`), subversion has lost track of files and all history is broken.

I know I should have used `svn mv` in order to keep history, but coming from git I didn't realize it was needed until it was too late. My question is: is there any way of telling subversion which repository file corresponds to each working copy file? It seems [it's somewhat possible manually executing svn commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4763989/2067969), but I would need to do it file by file, and frankly it's a lot of work. I could write a script that, for each file in my "broken" working copy searches in repository by name/MD5, and then performs the right `svn mv`, but I would'nt want to reinvent the wheel, since I think this may be a common error.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

After searching a little, I just found that Tortoise SVN is somewhat able to fix this kind of "bad moves", but for single files only, and there's also a tool called [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) that seems to be able to do it for large sets of files, but since is not free I haven't been able to try it.

In the end I wrote a small bash script that, for each file in the "wrong" working copy tries to find its original path, undo it and perform the proper `svn mv`. I [uploaded it](https://github.com/jesjimher/fixsvn) to Github, but please use it at your own risk.